# Duplicate worksheets using xlwt

Tags: python, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

I'm trying to convert a config file into an Excel file using xlwt. Getting an error because of duplicate worksheets. The config file is massive, I want to merge the duplicate worksheets . Is there a way to go around it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Below some idea for check duplicate sheets:

```
import xlwt

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
#Adding 2 sheets
ws1 = wb.add_sheet('One')
ws2 = wb.add_sheet('Two')

sheets = wb._Workbook__worksheets #Getting sheets list
sheet_names = [] #List for shhets names
for sheet in sheets:
     sheet_names.append(
         sheet.get_name() #getting sheet name
         ) 
print sheet_names
print True if u"One" in sheet_names else False #check for our name
wb.save('test.xls')
```

Results:

```
$python simple.py 
[u'One', u'Two']
True
```

Comment: In one time I hacked pyExcelerator, which is predecessor of xlwt. Read xlwt sources. You will find many interesting :)

Comment: Neat! Yep quite interesting stuff :)